# How to delete sublist in a list (with DeleteCase or similar)?

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I like to delete the sublist that have the second element "" (or any other you can set as "-1" or "A")

In the next example, I would like to erase the first and third sublist. How can I do this with `DeleteCases` or a similar way?. Thinking in larger lists.

```
a = {
  {"A", "", 0, 23},
  {"B", "ber", 0, 23},
  {"C", "", 0, 23},
  {"D", "der", 0, 23},
  {"E", "eer", 0, 23}
  }
DeleteCases[a, a[[i, 2]] == ""]
```

======================
**SOLVED  in the comment of J.M.**

Comment: `DeleteCases[a, {_, "", __}]`.

Comment: @J.M. thank you,  ok. The documentation is not much usefull for me. This forum is the best for learning.

Comment: If you understood how that worked, consider writing an answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Use only [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html):

```
a = {{"A", "", 0, 23}, {"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"C", "", 0, 23}, {"D", 
   "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{A} & \text{} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{B} & \text{ber} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{C} & \text{} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{D} & \text{der} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{E} & \text{eer} & 0 & 23 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Delete[a, {{1}, {3}}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \text{B} & \text{ber} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{D} & \text{der} & 0 & 23 \\
>  \text{E} & \text{eer} & 0 & 23 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{"A", "", 0, 23}, {"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"C", "", 0, 23},
     {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}};
```

---

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[a, {_, Except[""], ___}]

(*{{"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}}*)
```

Or using `Pick`:

```
Pick[#, Map[#[[2]] =!= "" &, #]] &@a

(*{{"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 
 {{"A", "", 0, 23}, {"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"C", "", 0, 23}, 
  {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[a, {{_, "", __}}]
```

{{"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{"A", "", 0, 23}, {"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"C", "", 0, 23}, {"D", 
    "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}};

delpos = Position[a[[All, 2]], "A" | ""]

Delete[a, delpos]
```

or to add an `Alternative` to J.M.'s comment:

```
DeleteCases[a, {_, "" | "A", __}]
```

or

```
Select[a, FreeQ[#[[2]], "" | "A"] &]
```

---

> {{"B", "ber", 0, 23}, {"D", "der", 0, 23}, {"E", "eer", 0, 23}}